# MyBatis Data Mapping. Collection. Relational Tables

Tags: mysql, sql, mybatis

**fund_allocation_template**

**template_id** | **template_name** | **status** |

1              Mega Lotto       1

2               EZ-2            1

**fund_allocation_item**

| item_id | item_name | status |

1  Charity  1

2  Operation Expenses  1

3  Food Allowance  1

4  Transportation Allowance  1

| 5 | Calamity Victims   | 1 |

**r_template_item**

| **template_id** | **item_id** | **item_percentage** |

1  1  45.00

1  2  55.00

2  1  40.00

2  2  46.00

```
//FundAllocationTemplate.java(domain)
private Integer templateID;
private String templateName;
private Integer templateStatus

//FundAllocationItem.java(domain)
private Integer itemID;
private String itemName;
private Integer itemStatus

<resultMap id="fundTemplate" type="FundAllocationTemplate">
    <id property="fundTemplateID"           column="template_id" />
    <result property="fundTemplateName"         column="template_name" />
    <result property="fundTemplateStatus"       column="status" />
    //Association for Status
</resultMap>

<resultMap id="fundItem" type="FundAllocationItem">
    <id property="fundItemID"       column="item_id" />
    <result property="fundItemName"     column="item_name" />
    <result property="fundItemStatus"   column="status" />
    //Association for Status
</resultMap>

FORM
private Integer templateID;
private String templateName;
private BigDecimal totalPercentage;
private Integer status;
```

### Form Or Page Output

### | Allocation Template Name | Fund Template Percentage | Status |

|        Mega Lotto        |           100%           | Active |

### |          EZ-2            |            86%           | Active |

Question: How can I be able to show the total percentage of every Fund Template with the given domain and table design?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following query:

```
select T.template_name,SUM(R.item_percentage) as Fund_Template_Percentage, 
(CASE T.status WHEN 1 THEN "Active" ELSE "NOT Active" END) STATUS 
from fund_allocation_template T, r_template_item R 
where T.template_id=R.template_id
GROUP BY R.template_id;
```

Comment: It runs when I run it in MySql Workbench but when I applied it to our program, I've encountered some errors because we have no Fund_Template_Percentage in our domain and ResultMap. Do you have any idea on how to use collection?

Comment: you can have a resultType="hashmap" and you will get List<Map<Object, Object>> in the java class. For each row, you can retrieve Fund_Template_Percentage as list.get(i).get("Fund_Template_Percentage") where i is the row number.